# Javascript piece of code not working

Tags: javascript, event-listener, attachevent

My javascript code isn't working, it's supposed to calculate the total price of lunch menu items and give the total result but nothing is coming up. The html is working fine, so I'm just writing the javascript section here, it's short. I literally followed directions to get this code, so I don't get what's wrong. Thank you :)

```
function calcTotal()
{
    var itemTotal=0;
    var items=document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
    //collects them into a NodeList object, which has indices

    for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(items[i].checked)
        itemTotal+=(items[i].value*1); //the *1 turns it into a number
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML="Your order total is $"+itemTotal + ".00";
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("sButton");
    if(submitButton.addEventListener)
    {
        submitButton.addEventListener("click",calcTotal,false);
    }

    else if(submitButton.attachEvent)
    {
        submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", calcTotal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the HTML as well please.

Comment: Please review how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Separating the model and the view would be nice and easier to debug... It is not possible to reproduce the error based on your example code.

Comment: We need to see how and when and where this function is being called.

Comment: Ohhh I didn't call it. I was supposed to call it in the javascript section. I'm sorry, this was a stupid question, I'm just completely new :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we need to see the HTML, but on first glance, I'd say it's because you are trying to set up your event bindings inside the event callback which won't get called unless you've set up the event bindings. You must set those up fist:

```
// First set up the event handling
var submitButton = document.getElementById("sButton");

// In this case, you can just check window to see if it has the property
if(window.addEventListener) {
  submitButton.addEventListener("click",calcTotal,false);
} else if(window.attachEvent)  {
  submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", calcTotal);
}

// And, have the callback separate
function calcTotal() {
    var itemTotal=0;
    var items=document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
    //collects them into a NodeList object, which has indices

    for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
        if(items[i].checked)
        itemTotal+=(items[i].value*1); //the *1 turns it into a number
    }

    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML="Your order total is $"+itemTotal + ".00";
}
```

Comment: This wasn't the actual problem, but thanks for the response!

Comment: That may not be the only problem, but it definitely was a problem. You can't set up an event handler in a function that doesn't get called except for when it is in response to the very event it is suppose to handle.

Comment: Is that true in javascript? Because I've seen alot of weird things happen in javascript that wouldn't normally be done..

Comment: It's absolutely the case. Without a doubt. You don't hook up a callback function in the callback function.